# How to separe mathematical operation from math expression like: 'log(2*x)*cos(x)'?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I would like to separate this math expression `'log(2*x)*cos(x)'` into `'log(2*x)'` and `'cos(x)'`. Im using Sympy to solve each part of the expression. I tried regex and ast.parse to separate math operation by parts but I didn't succeeded.

What I'm trying to do is to solve `'log(2*x)'` first, `'cos(x)'` second and then `'log(2*x)*cos(x)'`. How can I get each math operation from an math expression?

Comment: Are you always using this format `x(a)operationy(b)`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It seems you should also need to first resolve 2x...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't be doing this using regular expressions.  You should be letting sympy parse it, and sympy separate it into terms.

```
>>> expr = log(2 * x) * cos(x)
>>> expr.as_ordered_factors()
[log(2*x), cos(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of SymPy objects exposes the `args` attribute: it returns the arguments of an operator or a function. For example:

```py
from sympy import *
var("x")
expr = log(2*x)*cos(x)
print(expr.args)
# out: (cos(x), log(2*x))
```

Here, your expression is a multiplication and `args` returned its factors.

Let's consider an addition:

```py
expr = log(2*x) + cos(x)
print(expr.args)
# out: (cos(x), log(2*x))
```

Let's now consider a function:

```
expr = log(2*x)
print(expr.args)
# out: (2*x,)
```